# Does a vector behave the same was as an array when dealing with pointers?

Tags: c++

Is the name of a `vector` simply a pointer, just like a vanilla C array?

Thus, I could send the address to a single piece of non-vector data (a pointer, in other words) to a function argument that expects a `vector` since a `vector` is also a pointer.

For example, a function that is declared as this:

```
void RenderingEngine::Render(const vector<Visual>& visuals) const{
```

Could be called like this:

```
Visual visual; // is NOT a vector
//do stuff with visual
m_renderingEngine->Render(&visual);
```

Makes sense and is valid, legal C++?

This example code is from an O'Reilly C++ book, so I guess it is an error in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That doesn't make sense. There is no implicit conversion from `T*` to `std::vector<T>`.

But in C++11, you can do something which is very close<sup>1</sup> to what you're doing. You could create the vector on the fly while passing the argument as:

```
m_renderingEngine->Render( {visual} );  //note the curly braces!
```

With that you create a vector object out of the expression `{visual}` which then gets passed to the function.

---

<sup>1. *very close* in the sense that you just have to type *one more* character to make your code work. Instead of typying `&`, just type `{`, and one more `}` at the end. That is it. Life is so easy with C++11.</sup>

Comment: UPDATE: I should point out that this example code is from an O'Reilly C++ book, so I guess it is an error in the book.

Answer (score 2):

> Is the name of a vector simply a pointer, just like a vanilla C array?

No.  It's a fully-formed class.<sup>*</sup>

---

<sub>* What's more, a vanilla C array is not a pointer either (it just get turns into one in most situations).</sub>

Comment: UPDATE: I should point out that this example code is from an O'Reilly C++ book, so I guess it is an error in the book.

Comment: @SebbyJohanns: the could compile if there's also another overload of the member function that takes a Visual*.

Answer (score 1):

No, it isn't, which is rather fortunate because the behaviour of C arrays is abominable. If you find yourself looking for it, I would suggest instead looking for some new learning material w.r.t. C++.

Comment: UPDATE: I should point out that this example code is from an O'Reilly C++ book, so I guess it is an error in the book.

Comment: Or, more likely, O'Reilly just doesn't know what he's talking about- an unfortunately extremely common situation for C++ authors.

Comment: O'Reilly is a publisher, not a person, and one of the most respected in the industry. The author himself is quite well-known and now develops the studio graphics tools for Pixar.

Comment: Unfortunately, that really does not at all preclude the possibility that he has absolutely no idea what he's talking about w.r.t. C++. However, the possibility of a simple typo/etc should not be excluded.

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are correct, but I'd like to add that it works the other way around:

```
void RenderingEngine::Render(Visual *visuals, size_t n_visuals);
```

Can be called like this:

```
vector<Visual> visuals;
m_renderingEngine->Render(&visuals[0], visuals.size());
```

You just take the address of the first element and pass it as if it was an array. This works because the elements of a vector are laid out sequentially in memory. (As pointed out in the comments, shouldn't use this in new code, of course. It's safer and easier to define you method to take a vector. However, if you already have a legacy function that takes a pointer, this allows you to use vectors in your own code.)

---

The reason it works this way around, but not the way in your question (pass a pointer, to a function that takes a vector), is that in your case it can't determine the size of the array at runtime. But it has to know the size to construct the vector:

```
// (wrong code)
// Passing one element:
Visual visual;
m_renderingEngine->Render(&visual);

// Passing two elements, how does Render know that
// there are two elements at that address?
Visual[2] visuals;
m_renderingEngine->Render(&visuals[0]);
```

As Nawaz pointed out, you can do something similar in C++11:

```
Visual visual;
m_renderingEngine->Render( {visual} ); // C++11
```

You can also put more elements in the `{}`. This only works because the compiler can tell at compile-time how many elements there will be. It's just syntactic sugar for:

```
vector<Visual> myVec = {visual};  // C++11
m_renderingEngine->Render(myVec);
```

which in turn works like the classic:

```
vector<Visual> myVec;
myVec.push_back(visual);
m_renderingEngine->Render(myVec);
```

(although the C++11 version might be slightly optimized, I don't know for sure).

Comment: We could write everything in C too if we wanted, but that doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: Whoa, why the downvotes? The answer is correct as far as I can see. I'm not recommending using pointers, I'm answering the OPs question. In some situations, a vector *does* behave like a plain C array, because it uses a plain array representation underneath. This is extremely useful if you have to call legacy code that takes pointers, but you want to use vectors in your own code.

Comment: It is correct, but the probability of the OP using it correctly over the lifespan of his application is slim. This function is not a legacy function, and using such an interface is a supremely bad idea.

Comment: I found this answer educational, if not something I'd actually use personally. Not worth all the downvotes, but worth a disclaimer that it's more theory than practice.